# Android find all method calls for a higher api version

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently ran into a problem where I tested my app on an older version of Android (API 12) and my target API level is 22. When I ran it in Honeycomb it was crashing do to a method call that is for API 16.

My question is, how can I find all method calls that are for a higher version than my minSDKVersion (which is 11)? Just to make sure Im not making that mistake anywhere else in my app.

By the way, Im using Android Studio

Thanks for any help

Comment: you should be able to see the deprecated symbol on android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Compile your project with the lowest api that u support. Then all of
  the *newer* methods will be with errors.
- Run lint to see all of the warnings and filter them for *@SuppressLint("NewApi")*

Comment: Ooh I see, I had to change the compileSdkVersion in the build.gradle file. I though just having the minSdkVersion set would do it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the deprecated symbol like this for older api methods

[image]

you can also check api level and provide alternative methods like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
} else {
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
}
```